# How to set rocksdb memtable size in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to limit the rocsdb's memtable size. I have a few question:
1, is taskmanager.memory.size configuration include the rocksdb memtable's memory amount?
2, is there any configuration can set rocksdb memtable size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. RocksDB memory is not included in Flink's memory parameters. You have to make sure that Flink leaves enough memory for RocksDB. However, this is not trivial, because Flink will use one RocksDB instance for each instance of a stateful operator. This means the number of RocksDB instances per TaskManager depends on the number of stateful operators in your job and the parallelism of these operators (each TM runs at most #slots instances of an operator).
2. You can pass any RocksDB parameters when you configure the RocksDBStateBackend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, is the "taskmanager.heap.mb" parameter has any effect on stream job? My stream job's running on a cluster that deployed on yarn,  my job always be killed by yarn because of memory limited. I had configured the "taskmanager.heap.mb" parameter, but it still exceed the value I configured.

Comment: The `taskmanager.heap.mb` parameter specifies the size of the JVM of the TM. However, there is also memory allocation outside of the JVM like Netty and RocksDB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.